# Can't run a command in a batch file while in command prompt it executes

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line, cmd

Been stuck on this for a while now, I've tried finding the answer on this and similar forums but nothing worked.

I got this command:

```
 FOR /F "tokens=3 skip=1" %i IN (C:\logoff\query.txt) DO logoff %i /server:192.168.0.231
```

Where basically it takes number from query.txt file and it loggs off the user from server by his session id number.

It works if I execute command in a command prompt, but I can't seems to get it working on a batch. I've tried doubling the percentage signs, like someone suggested in forums - nothing.

I assume to confirm the command should work on batch it should execute using "Run...", it doesn't though..

Is the problem that the command starts with `FOR` or what is the case? I give up..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
for /F "usebackq tokens=3 skip=1 delims=|" %%i in ("C:\logoff\query.txt") do logoff %%i /server:192.168.0.231
```

I thing you problem is like **@MC ND** said and you forget to use **delims**.

in you **query.txt** must something like this:

```
1|1|111
2|2|222
3|3|333
```

output:

```
logoff 222 /server:192.168.0.231
logoff 333 /server:192.168.0.231
```

Answer (score 1):

The `for` replaceable parameters (the "variable" containing the current value of the iteration) uses the `%x` syntax. But inside a batch file, the percent sign needs to be escaped and the syntax is `%%x` (see `for /?`).

```
FOR /F "tokens=3 skip=1" %%i IN (C:\logoff\query.txt) DO logoff %%i /server:192.168.0.231
                         ^^                                     ^^
```